# Other invariants than (co)homology and homotopy groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

In algebraic topology one investigates topological spaces $X$ by looking at

- their singular homology groups $H_n(X)$,
- their singular cohomology groups $H^n(X)$, and
- their homotopy groups $\pi_n(X)$.

However, I never saw any other invariant than (co)homology or homotopy groups.

**Question:** Is it possible that someone comes up with a completely new invariant? Or is there a theorem which states *something* in the direction that the above invariants are sufficient (for some purposes)?

Comment: An interesting result is Brown's representability theorem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown%27s_representability_theorem

Comment: Aside from the groups themselves, there are other structures that one can use to distinguish spaces. For example, the direct sum of the cohomology groups have a ring structure, and the higher homotopy groups have the structure of $\pi_1$-modules. In addition, cohomology with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients has the structure of a module over the Steenrod algebra - see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2078503/39599) for an example of two spaces which cannot be distinguished using the prior structures, but can by using this additional one.

Comment: There are also extraordinary cohomology theories like K-theory or cobordism theories.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335112/other-homotopy-invariants.